# Calling pack_forget () in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a Python program that looks like this

```
from tkinter import *
import threading, time
def cancel ():
    print ("Stop!")
def thread ():
    threading.Thread (target = new).start ()
def new ():
    b.pack_forget ()
    c = Canvas (root, width = 200, height = 25, bg = "white")
    c.pack ()
    Button (root, text = "OK", command = root.destroy).pack ()
    try:
        for x in range (200):
            time.sleep (0.02)
            c.create_rectangle ((x, 2, x + 1, 26), outline = "green", fill = "green")
        root.destroy ()
    except: pass
root = Tk ()
root.title ("Threading")
b = Button (root, text = "Begin.", command = thread)
b.pack ()
root.mainloop ()
```

However, it crashes every time I call the pack_forget (). I know I can do it like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading, time
def cancel ():
    print ("Stop!")
def thread ():
    b.pack_forget ()
    threading.Thread (target = new).start ()
def new ():
    c = Canvas (root, width = 200, height = 25, bg = "white")
    c.pack ()
    Button (root, text = "OK", command = root.destroy).pack ()
    try:
        for x in range (200):
            time.sleep (0.02)
            c.create_rectangle ((x, 2, x + 1, 26), outline = "green", fill = "green")
        root.destroy ()
    except: pass
root = Tk ()
root.title ("Threading")
b = Button (root, text = "Begin.", command = thread)
b.pack ()
root.mainloop ()
```

For other programs, though, is it possible to call pack_forget in a thread. Thanks.

Comment: Your first block runs for me, but I have had issues in the past with controlling tkinter objects from several different threads. I would not recommend doing that. Why don't you just use tkinter's `after` method instead of a thread?

Comment: This is a demonstration program. In my full program, I am using it on a piece of code that varies massively in the time taken to finish.

Comment: In your real program are you also trying to control a progress bar? Using tkinter variables is threadsafe, so you could tie your progress bar to an IntVar and then call int_var.set() from the other thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call tkinter functions from a thread other than the thread where you created the GUI. You need to set up a thread-safe queue, and from the worker thread place something on the queue. The main thread can poll this queue and respond to the data.

For example, you could put something as simple as `"pack_forget"` on the queue, and when the main program pulls the string `"pack_forget"` off of the queue, it knows to call that function.

Comment: How would I do this (sorry, I'm relatively new)?

Comment: You can use a timer, and set it again at the end of the block of code you need to run. As long as you initialize the timer from the main thread running the GUI, it will work. self.root.after(100, self.check_for_results)